# If $abc=1$, prove that $\frac{2}{(a+1)^2+b^2+1} + \frac{2}{(b+1)^2+c^2+1} + \frac{2}{(c+1)^2+a^2+1} \le 1$.

Tags: inequality

If $a, b, c \in \mathbb{N}$, and $abc = 1$, prove that:
$$S = \frac{2}{(a+1)^2+b^2+1} + \frac{2}{(b+1)^2+c^2+1} + \frac{2}{(c+1)^2+a^2+1} \le 1$$

Here is my try:
$$\begin{align}\frac{2}{(a+1)^2+(b^2+1)} & \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{(a+1)^2 \cdot (b^2+1)}}\\
& = \frac{1}{(a+1) \cdot \sqrt{b^2+1}}\\
& \le \frac{1}{(a+1) \cdot b}\\
& \le \frac{1}{ab}
\end{align}$$

So,
$$S \le \frac{1}{ab} + \frac{1}{bc} + \frac{1}{ca} = \frac{a+b+c}{1}$$

Can you help me to continue it, please? Thanks!

Comment: If $abc = 1$ and $a,b,c$ are integers then $a=b=c=1$. Is $a,b,c\in\mathbb{N}$ a typo?

Comment: I think it must be $a,b,c>0$

Comment: You have to start over: $S \leq a+b+c$ is not strong enough to give you $S \leq 1$. The inequalities you have used are not good enough. Note that when $a=b=c=1$ then we have the equality $S = 1$. Any inequality you use must be sharp for this case (and for example $\frac{1}{(a+1)b}\leq \frac{1}{ab}$ for $a=b=1$ reads $\frac{1}{2} \leq 1$ which is not).

Comment: @Winther, yes, thank you. I think it was a typo in my book. I didn't notice it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem from [Olympiad Inequalities](https://artofproblemsolving.com/articles/files/MildorfInequalities.pdf), Thomas J. Mildorf, 2005 (short but wonderful reading with many different ideas, a true gem). The idea presented here (replacing $a,b,c$ with $x/y,y/z,z/x$) is often used to normalize the inequality in case of $abc=1$.

[image]